# UIBezierPath:How to use - (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point onPath:(UIBezierPath *)path inFillArea:(BOOL)inFill method to fill an image?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, touch, uibezierpath

I have an image .PNG (e.g. an animal image with black outline only)and i want to fill gradient by touch on iPad screen.

I'm following Apple's guide from here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

Following Apple's guide :

```
- (BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)point onPath:(UIBezierPath *)path inFillArea:  
   (BOOL)inFill {

NSLog(@"contains point Path %@", path);
NSLog(@"Touch point %f %f", point.x, point.y );

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPathRef cgPath = path.CGPath;
BOOL    isHit = NO;
// Determine the drawing mode to use. Default to detecting hits on the stroked     
  portion of the path.
CGPathDrawingMode mode = kCGPathStroke;

if (inFill) { // Look for hits in the fill area of the path instead.
    if (path.usesEvenOddFillRule)
        mode = kCGPathEOFill;
    else
        mode = kCGPathFill;
}

 // Save the graphics state so that the path can be removed later.

CGContextSaveGState(context);

 CGContextAddPath(context, cgPath);

// Do the hit detection.
isHit = CGContextPathContainsPoint(context, point, mode);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

return isHit; }
```

I just want to know how can i use this method in my app.

Tell me what is the steps for that?

I am new in this please help me....

Comment: I can ask this type of questions?